# Why does this get a syntax error when exec() is called?

Tags: python

I have a database of questions, and a few of those questions have need of special validation.  So, I added a field to my model called py_validation and when those questions are answered, I validate them by running the code that is stored in py_validation.  When I paste the code into the interpereter, it works correctly, but when I pass it into exec, it fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <fragment>
invalid syntax: <string>, line 2, pos 31
```

The code looks like:

```
# This code relies on the field type being a char field
if len(value.split('\n')) < 5:
    raise ValidationError(_("You must specify at least 5 widgets, one per line"))
super(CharField, self).validate(value)
```

I'm calling it using:

```
def do_py_validate(field, value):
    exec field.py_validation
```

so that variable value is in local scope while executing.  Doesn't quite make sense that the code that works just fine, bails when executed like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out to have a simple answer.  The string contained \r characters that python was not happy swallowing.  The answer came as I was trying to figure out how to make a file like object to read the string from.  The solution is:

```
def do_py_validate(field, value):
    exec field.py_validation.replace('\r', '')
```

This was almost as much fun as programming in [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).